# Dynamic Recongure callback seems to happen spontaneously

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that's imposible. Help me spot my mistake. I think I am just launching the camera (raspicam_node) and suddenly out of nowhere comes a dynamic reconfigure. I was playing with that before but now to troubleshoot as far as I can tell, everything is off and all I have is:

```
/base_link_to_camera
/raspicam_node
/rosout
```

And yet, see the call too dynamic reconfigure in this log. I know I am not understanding some detail, but I can't figure out what!.

Thanks,

Pito

```
PARAMETERS
 * /raspicam_node/camera_frame_id: raspicam
 * /raspicam_node/camera_id: 0
 * /raspicam_node/camera_info_url: package://raspica...
 * /raspicam_node/camera_name: camerav2_1280x960
 * /raspicam_node/enable_imv: False
 * /raspicam_node/enable_raw: False
 * /raspicam_node/exposure_mode: antishake
 * /raspicam_node/framerate: 10
 * /raspicam_node/height: 960
 * /raspicam_node/private_topics: True
 * /raspicam_node/shutter_speed: 0
 * /raspicam_node/vFlip: 0
 * /raspicam_node/width: 1280
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.14

NODES
  /
    base_link_to_camera (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    raspicam_node (raspicam_node/raspicam_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [2579]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://100.64.81.29:11311

setting /run_id to 15542e90-d1c1-11ed-a130-518a9bdbf4c9
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2589]
started core service [/rosout]
process[raspicam_node-2]: started with pid [2596]
process[base_link_to_camera-3]: started with pid [2597]
[ INFO] [1680486285.632388511]: splitter component done

[ INFO] [1680486285.872005087]: camera calibration URL: package://raspicam_node/camera_info/camerav2_1280x960.yaml
[ INFO] [1680486286.080336951]: Camera successfully calibrated from default file
[ INFO] [1680486286.080749447]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1680486286.081100851]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/ubuntu/.ros/camera_info/camerav2_1280x960.yaml
[ INFO] [1680486286.081757617]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/ubuntu/.ros/camera_info/camerav2_1280x960.yaml]
[ WARN] [1680486286.082066000]: Camera calibration file /home/ubuntu/.ros/camera_info/camerav2_1280x960.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1680486286.082351102]: No device specifc calibration found
[ INFO] [1680486286.222915249]: Reconfigure Request: contrast 0, sharpness 0, brightness 50, saturation 0, ISO 400, exposureCompensation 0, videoStabilisation 0, vFlip 1, hFlip 0, zoom 1.00, exposure_mode antishake, awb_mode auto, shutter_speed 0
[ INFO] [1680486286.290719372]: Starting video capture (1280, 960, 80, 10)

[ INFO] [1680486286.292337641]: Video capture started!!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413992/dynamic-recongure-callback-seems-to-happen-spontaneously/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2023-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-04-03**:
PS: for future questions: please always either link to the wiki page for the package you are using, or a source repository.

There are multiple `raspicam_node` packages with the exact same name, but in completely disconnected repositories. Without more information from you to uniquely identify *which* one you are using, it's impossible to be certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I think I am just launching the camera (raspicam_node) and suddenly out of nowhere comes a dynamic reconfigure.

I'm almost certain this is the default behaviour for `dynamic_reconfigure` servers.

See #q28327 fi (also the answer by @joq ), #q250134 and finally the source of `dynamic_configure`'s `Server::setCallback(..)`  itself (from [here](https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/blob/2654f228adae0848c6e9b70fcf07f890ca6a2841/include/dynamic_reconfigure/server.h#L85-L91)):

> ```
> void setCallback(const CallbackType &callback)
> ```

```
{
  boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);
  callback_ = callback;
  callCallback(config_, ~0); // At startup we need to load the configuration with all level bits set. (Everything has changed.)
  updateConfigInternal(config_);
}
```

Notice how it calls `callCallback(..)` right after storing the `callback` is assigned to `callback_` (ie: the member variable).

This lets the server load the default values for all parameters using the same callback that is used to handle any incoming reconfigure requests from actual clients.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2023-04-03**:
You're correct. The surprising thing is that this overrides parameters set in the launch file in favor of the default parameters specified in the dynamic configure setup.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-04-03**:
That's discussed in #q250134.

Seems to be a problem in the node, not of `dynamic_reconfigure` itself.